# Q how to enter API functions in wsclient rest server setting?

Tags: 8, services

I need to add functions from an SDK API reference document to the Drupal7 webservices rest server. I'd like to query them through the wsclient rest server, attached to a feed, to input them as analytics into the node of the content they are viewing at the time.

Eg one of the API references listed (which I want to use is);
Float AffGetEScore()
Description:
Returns EB level of the user.
Parameters:
Returns:
EB level (0.0 to 1.0).

I have created a field in my node (type 'float') labeled 'AffGetEscore' and set up the wsclient. Now how/where does this function get entered in the Drupal webservices rest server settings?Where can I find 'Escore' in my settings to select? How/where do I enter this function in the wsclient settings? Thank you so much- would very much appreciate any guidance/ help you can give.